# List of lists, take next element

Tags: list, function, haskell, list-comprehension, element

I have `[[Integer]] -> [Integer]` and want to take the first element of the first sub-list, the second element of the second sub-list and .. the *n*-th element of the *n*-th sub-list and so on.

I am trying to achieve this using list comprehensions. However, I first drop an incrementing number of elements and the take the head of the remaining. But there again I don't know how to use `drop (inc z) where z = 0` with `inc c = c + 1` as an already defined function, in presumably this:

```
getNext :: [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
getNext xs = [y | drop (inc z) (y:ys) <- xs, (y:_) <- xs]
           where z = 0
```

I know that the code above is not working, but again I had only so far come up to this and hit a wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
getNext :: [[a]] -> [a]
getNext xs = [ head $ drop y x | (x,y) <- zip xs [0..]]
```

Although note that this function is partial because of `head`.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers suggest, you can use a `zip` function and `zip` with the list of indices.

The *Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC)* however offers the [*Parallel List Comp*](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/ParallelListComp) extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

diagonal :: [[a]] -> [a]
diagonal ls = [l !! i | l <- ls | i <- [0..]]
```

The [`(!!)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) operator gets the *i*-th element from a list.

Furthermore it is always advisable to *use the most generic function signature*; so `[[a]] -> [a]` instead of `[[Integer]] -> [Integer]`. This can be useful if you later decide to take the diagonal of a matrix of `Double`'s, `String`, lists, custom types,...

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the actual list of list of integers and another list which runs from `0` to infinity and get the corresponding elements, like this

```
picker :: [[Integer]] -> [Integer]
picker xs = [(x !! y) | (x, y) <- (zip xs [0..])]

main = print $ picker [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
-- [1,5,9]
```

The expression `[0..]` will create an infinite list, lazily, starting from `0` and we `zip` it with `xs`. So, on every iteration, the result of `zip` would be used like this

```
[1, 2, 3] !! 0
[4, 5, 6] !! 1
[7, 8, 9] !! 2
```

We get element at index `0`, which is `1`, on the first iteration and `5` and `9` on the following iterations.